# Full Calendar implemented using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to implement FullCalendar using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = $('#calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
});
```

but the calendar doesn't show on the browser

-for more information about the FullCalendar:[FullCalendar][1]-
[1]: https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: You need to supply a DOM element to the fullCalendar constructor, not a jQuery object. They are not the same thing. Just follow the demo, it's simple: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals . You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: ok.....

but I'm trying to use jQuery to ease stuff out but it also is not working, so even if I used the way they using it I'm not able to use the selectors of jQuery

Comment: `I'm trying to use jQuery to ease stuff out`...sure, jQuery can be useful for that sometimes. But in this case it doesn't actually achieve anything useful. It's just causing you a problem instead. `even if I used the way they using it I'm not able to use the selectors of jQuery` ...and what would you need those for, in your code above? Again it's not useful. P.S. The "selectors of jQuery" are actually CSS selectors (aside from a few extra ones jQuery introduced for edge cases) so you can actually use the same ones with `document.querySelector`, if you prefer, instead of document.getElementById

Comment: And you don't even need `initialView: 'dayGridMonth'` either because that's already the default! This is all you need to get a basic calendar up and running: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGgEPPK - I've used document.querySelector instead of document.getElementById, so you can use the same "selector" as you did in the jQuery.

Comment: Er, I definitely answered the question. The answer is "don't use jQuery for this, it's not useful". fullCalendar expects a DOM element, so give it a DOM element. Simple.

Comment: this is just a start up for my code the code is a big part and uses google calendar and thank you for you answer it did not help

Comment: Why not? That **is** the answer. Use a DOM element. Simple. There's no other option if you want it to work. If you want to use jQuery somewhere else in your page, you can write `$("#calendar")` elsewhere in your code to select the calendar object, if it's useful for you. You just can't use it to initialise the calendar. I can't really see why that's a problem for you.

Comment: the code well get bigger so not using jQuery will make it harder.... 

no thanks to you

Comment: I've just said, you can use jQuery as much as you want in the rest of your code. Just not for this part.

Comment: even using $("#calendar") did not work I've tried every thing

Comment: you are just repeating the point that I said......

Comment: I used the code in the documentation before you tell me and it worked, tried to implement some jQuery inside the code -some were else from you said- but it did not work

Comment: `some were else from you said` no I never said anything about using jQuery from somewhere else, not sure what you mean by that. Did you misunderstand me, perhaps? There _is_ a way to use jQuery here but it's pointless and inefficient. I have answered the question formally below with all of your options.

Comment: `you are just repeating the point that I said`...no you were making a different point entirely. Again I think you misunderstood me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FullCalendar accepts an [Element object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) into its constructor. It does not accept a jQuery object. You cannot use a jQuery object in the way you've shown in your code. jQuery doesn't give you any advantages in this situation. (This does not prevent you from using jQuery elsewhere in your page, you just can't use a jQuery object to initialise the calendar.)

Ways to get an Element object:

1. Use [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) as shown in the [fullCalendar introductory guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals) - e.g. `document.getElementById("calendar");`
2. use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) - e.g. `document.querySelector('#calendar')`
3. If, for some reason, you really insist on having the unnecessary overhead of using a jQuery constructor and object, then you can create a jQuery object using `$("#calendar")` and then get the first matched `Element` object out of it by using `$("#calendar")[0]`, and pass that to fullCalendar. But this is inefficient and unnecessary. jQuery is just getting in your way if you do this, without adding any value.

Here's a simple example of initialising the calendar using `document.querySelector`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.querySelector('#calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGgEPPK

---

P.S. If you then wanted to use jQuery to do more things to the calendar element, after the `calendar.render()` line you could easily wrap the `calendarEl` in a jQuery object so you can then use jQuery functions with it for other purposes. For example:

```
var calendarEl = document.querySelector('#calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
});

calendar.render();

var calendarjQ = $(calendarEl); //wrap calendarEl, which is an Element, in a jQuery object
// then do whatever you want with calendarjQ....
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really cleared my head as I didn't realize [this jQuery implementation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/usage) I keep trying to work is version 1 documentation. Cheers!